# Find all perfect squares of the form aaa...a (n digits) bbb...b (n digits)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find all perfect squares of the form $\underbrace{a \ldots a}_n  \underbrace{b\ldots b}_n$.

This is my homework for Discrete Mathematics. All I'm asking for is to better understand what exactly the question is asking. I'm not looking for the answer.

Comment: Find all perfect squares in the form $\underbrace{aaa\dots a}_{n\text{ times}}\underbrace{bbb\dots b}_{n\text{ times}}$, where $a$ and $b$ are decimal digits.

Comment: For what it's worth, in base ten, no squares end in $11$, $22$, $33$, $55$, $66$, $77$, $88$, $99$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you’re supposed to find all positive integers that are perfect squares, have $2n$ digits for some $n\ge 1$, and are such that the first $n$ digits are identical, and the last $n$ digits are identical. It’s not clear whether $a$ and $b$ are allowed to be equal. Examples with $n=1$ are easy: all two-digit squares work. A less trivial example is $88^2=7744$, with $n=2$, $a=7$, and $b=4$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is looking for squares that look like 333777, 88884444, etc. - a number of repetitions of one digit, followed by a number of repetitions of another digit.

(The problem is slightly ambiguous: can the "another digit" be the same, allowing a number that's just a single digit repeated an even number of times, like 5555?  What about where there's only a single repetition, like 36?  These probably don't make a big difference, but if you want to be thorough make sure to consider those cases.)